# Need explanation of natural ordering in Java

Tags: java, sorting, collections

Would you give an example of "choose the natural ordering inside the class."

I read Object Ordering in docs.oracle but it doesn't say how the natural ordering is decided in the case where there are multiple elements. If a class has elements such as name, age, address, phone number; which one gets picked to do the natural ordering?

Then, I read in a post here that one can decide the natural ordering.  I am a Java newbie trying to tackle a homework assignment and taking my first stab at the collections framework.

Comment: Either write your own `Comparator` to define ordering, or have the class implement the `Comparable` interface and provide an implementation in the `compareTo` method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I prefer Comparator classes for this, even though the implementation looks a bit more heavyweight. The reason is that, for some objects, it's not always clear what's being compared. Using `.compareTo()` (that is, implementing IComparable) doesn't make it as clear as an explicit Comparator does.

```
BasketballPlayer player1 = new BasketballPlayer("Smith", 2.02);
BasketballPlayer player2 = new BasketballPlayer("Jones", 1.95);

List<BasketballPlayer> playersByHeight = new ArrayList<BasketballPlayer>();
List<BasketballPlayer> playersByName = new ArrayList<BasketballPlayer>();
playersByHeight.add(player1);
playersByHeight.add(player2);
playersByName.add(player1);
playersByName.add(player2);

Collections.sort(playersByName, new Comparator<BasketballPlayer>() {
    @Override
    public int compare(BasketballPlayer o1, BasketballPlayer o2) {
        return o1.getName().compareTo(o2.getName());
    }
});
Collections.sort(playersByHeight, new Comparator<BasketballPlayer>() {
    @Override
    public int compare(BasketballPlayer o1, BasketballPlayer o2) {
        return o1.getHeight().compareTo(o2.getHeight());
    }
});
```

Here I use an anonymous class, but you could make the Comparators their own (named) class if you like.

Comment: Thank you very much.  I just need to get more experience writing comparators.

Comment: You'll figure it out... generally the underlying property is comparable, so you can just use its .compareTo() method to do the dirty work. And you can put a minus sign before the return value to reverse the order.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you are right in saying that one can decide the natural ordering.  You'd be implementing Comparable and writing your own implementation of the compareTo() method.  In that method, you decide what trumps what.

Comment: thank you.  I am trying to do just that, I mean write a comparator.